# how to use vue-loader to compile template part to string but not js render function

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

When I use vue-loader, I found html in  block compiled to js render function, but I want to it become simple html string.

I found in vue-loader postloaders part, the doc said: 
For html, the result returned by the default loader will be compiled JavaScript render function code.

Is there any way to config the postloaders, so it can pass the html content without any post processing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Looks like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800).

Comment: To get html not compiled to js function, so I can edit the compiled content easily.

Comment: _"edit the compiled content"_, why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: so I can do quick fix after I published to server. it is the requirement.